# Haskell error: cannot derive well-kinded instance / kind-mismatch

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I'm having trouble deriving a `Typeable1` instance for a date structure in Haskell.

This is my code:

```
    {-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
    {-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

    import Data.Typeable (Typeable,Typeable1)

    newtype FooM m a = Foo { unFoo :: (a -> Bar m) -> Bar m }
    newtype Bar m = Atom (m (Maybe (Bar m)))
    type Baz m = Waldo (FooM m ())
    type Waldo a = a

    data Qux m = Qux {
        baz :: Baz m
      , num :: Int
    } -- deriving Typeable1 [1]

    -- deriving instance Typeable1 Qux [2]
```

Uncommenting the first comment [1] gives this error:

```
    Cannot derive well-kinded instance of form `Typeable1 (Qux ...)'
          Class `Typeable1' expects an argument of kind `* -> *'
        In the data type declaration for `Qux'
```

And uncommenting [2] gives this error:

```
    Kind mis-match
    The first argument of `Typeable1' should have kind `* -> *',
    but `Qux' has kind `(* -> *) -> *'
    In the stand-alone deriving instance for `Typeable1 Qux'
```

My question is: How can I add a `Typeable`/`Typeable1` instance of `Qux`, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make `Qux` an instance of `Typeable1`, but in modern GHC, you should be able to derive an instance of `Typeable`, which is now kind-polymorphic enough to handle such higher-kinded types, making `Typeable1` and its ilk unnecessary.

Outdated answer, kept because it was the accepted answer when the question was asked: Unfortunately, you can't: the `Typeable` hierarchy doesn't have any typeclasses for things of kind `(* -> *) -> *`. This may be fixed at some future time now that GHC is starting to support kind polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

It was appear that this problem is currently being considered in the ghc ticket, [#5391](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5391). So there's a chance that the `deriving Typeable` problem will go away in GHC 7.6.